# For loop is stopping when rest of the block is added

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, fromcharcode

I wrote a simple for loop, to understand charCodeAt() and fromCharCode() better and to solve the odin project the Caesar cipher exercise where you have to write function to encode a string.

It stops at the first iteration and I don´t know why.
When I console log str.charCodeAt(i) it loops, but when I add the rest of the function it stops.

```
function uniCode(str, num) {
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
        //console.log(str.charCodeAt(i) + num);
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + num;
        let newStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        return newStr;
    }        
        
}
uniCode("Help!", 3);
'K'
```

Glad for any help!

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

with your code you loop through all characters of a given string in parameter

but you have `return newStr;` in the loop it will stop the loop iteration

```js
function uniCode(str, num) {
    var newStr = "";
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
        console.log(str.charCodeAt(i) + num);
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i);
        newStr += String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    }        
    console.log(newStr);
    return newStr;
        
}
uniCode("Help!", 3);
```

Comment: Putting `newStr` outside the function is poor practice. Instead, build the string in the function and return it.

Comment: yes thank you i fix my sample with your comment

Comment: Thanks! I totally forgot about return stopping the function

Answer (score 1):

It's stopping because you've told it to, by using `return newStr;`, which immediately terminates the function and returns `newStr`.

For what you're doing, you want to build up the new string and then return it at the end:

```
function uniCode(str, num) {
    let newStr = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + num;
        let newChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        newStr += newChar;
    }        
        
    return newStr;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function uniCode(str, num) {
    let newStr = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + num;
        let newChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        newStr += newChar;
    }        
        
    return newStr;
}

console.log(uniCode("Help!", 3)); // "Khos$"
```

**Beware**, though, that when you loop through a string like that, you're working in *code units*, not *code points*, which may make your results quite odd if there are code points requiring multiple code units to process. (See [my blog post here](https://thenewtoys.dev/blog/2021/01/26/what-is-a-string/) if these terms are unfamiliar.) You might want to use `for-of` instead, since it works in code points:

```
function uniCode(str, num) {
    let newStr = "";

    for (const char of str) {
        const codePointValue = char.codePointAt(0) + num;
        const newChar = String.fromCodePoint(codePointValue);
        newStr += newChar;
    }        
        
    return newStr;
}
```

Live Example:

```js
function uniCode(str, num) {
    let newStr = "";

    for (const char of str) {
        const codePointValue = char.codePointAt(0) + num;
        const newChar = String.fromCodePoint(codePointValue);
        newStr += newChar;
    }        
        
    return newStr;
}

function oldUniCode(str, num) {
    let newStr = "";

    for (let i = 0; i < str.length; i++) {
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + num;
        let newChar = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        newStr += newChar;
    }        
        
    return newStr;
}

console.log("New: " + uniCode("Help!", 3));    // "New: Khos$"
console.log("Old: " + oldUniCode("Help!", 3)); // "Old: Khos$"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I will read your blog post!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is the `return` statement at the end of the loop that causes the problem.

You can create a variable and append `newStr` to it and after the loop, return the string value

```
function uniCode(str, num) {
    let finalStr = ""
    for(let i = 0; i < str.length;i++) {
        let charCode = str.charCodeAt(i) + num;
        let newStr = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
        finalStr = finalStr + newStr;
    }        
 return finalStr       
}

uniCode("Help!", 3);
'Khos$'
```

You can make the code better by using `reduce` function like:

```
function uniCode(str, num) {
  return str
    .split('')
    .map(x=>x.charCodeAt(0))
    .reduce((total, curr) => (total + String.fromCharCode(curr + num)), "")
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Did not think about using reduce(). Reduce() is so flexible if you know how to handle it.